# Why doesn't this approach work for $\int \sec^4 x\,dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I been trying to integrate $\sec^4$ , without much luck. But I don't entirely understand why my result is invalid and would like some feedback if possible.

I'm attacking the issue in the following way

$$
\int (\sec^2{x})^2dx = \int (\tan^2+1)^2dx
$$

then, I put $u=\tan^2+1$ which means $x = \arctan(\sqrt{u-1})$, which allows me to do the following backwards substitution

$$
\int (\sec^2{x})^2dx = \int (\tan^2+1)^2dx = \int u^2 \frac{1}{2u\sqrt{u-1}} dx = \frac{1}{2}\int u (u-1)^{\frac{-1}{2}} dx 
$$

Now using integration by parts I get

$$\begin{align*}
\int u (u-1)^{\frac{-1}{2}} dx &= \frac{1}{2}(2u(u-1)^{\frac{1}{2}} - \int 2(u-1)^{\frac{1}{2}})\\\\
&= \frac{1}{2}(2u(u-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}-\frac{4}{3}(u-1)^{3/2}) \\\\
&= \frac{1}{2}(2(\tan^2{x}+1)(\tan^2{x})^{\frac{1}{2}}-\frac{4}{3}(\tan^2{x})^{3/2})
\end{align*}$$

This however, seems to be incorrect. How come?

Comment: You forgot the $+C$, and seem to have mixed up $du$, $dx$, and even forgotten them at one point, and I'm not sure if you've paid attention to signs and the domain of $x$. But that aside, are you *sure* it's incorrect? [Wolfram alpha thinks you have a correct antiderivative](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+of+%281%2F2%29+%282+%28%28tan+x%29%5E2+%2B+1%29+%28tan+x%29+-+%284%2F3%29+%28tan+x%29%5E3%29)

Comment: This is another point of confusion for me, try checking http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+of+%281%2F2%29+%282+%28%28tan+x%29%5E2+%2B+1%29+%28%28tan+x%29%5E2%29%5E%281%2F2%29+-+%284%2F3%29+%28%28tan+x%29%5E2%29%5E%283%2F2%29

Comment: WolframAlpha is being very careful with the signs you were glossing over. Note, for example, that when $\tan(x) > 0$, then $\sqrt{\tan(x)} \csc(x) = \sec(x)$.

Comment: I was guessing it was because I got rid of the powers wrong, as I should do $(\tan^2{x})^{1/2} = |tan{x}|$ instead.

Comment: But still, I did a test and did a definite integral, if I use the version before getting rid of the powers, I get a wrong result, after getting rid of the powers, I get a correct result. I thought it was because I got rid of the powers incorrectly.

Comment: It's $x = \arctan(\sqrt{u-1})$ that's wrong, since you assumed the positive square root and threw away the other solution with negative square root; that only works when $x \in [0, \pi/2)$. In particular, if $x \in (-\pi/2, 0]$, you should have taken the negative square root. ($x$ in other periods of the $\tan$ function, like $(\pi/2, 3\pi/2)$ can be dealt by noting only $dx$ and $\tan x$ actually matter, and, e.g., $d(x + \pi) = dx$ as well as $\tan(x+\pi) = \tan x$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be careful with solving the equations; solving the equation

$$ 1 + \tan^2 x = u $$

for $x$ in terms of $u$ actually has many possible values: they are the values

$$ \pi n \pm \arctan \sqrt{u-1} $$

where $n$ ranges over all integers.

Ultimately, we can ignore the $\pi n$ part when rewriting the integral, because $\tan(z + n \pi) = \tan(z)$ and $d(z + n \pi) = dz$, and these are the only sorts places $\pi n $ would appear in the equation. However, we mustn't forget the sign.

Rather than donig two problems separately, it is convenient to define a new varaible $s$ to be $1$ or $-1$ as appropriate, and

$$ x = \pi n + s \arctan \sqrt{u-1} $$

and $s$ can be treated as a constant (depending on what you imagine for the fine details either $s$ really is a constant or $s$ is "locally constant", but either way, $ds = 0$). In the final simplifications, observe that

$$ \tan x = s \sqrt{u - 1} $$

which lets you convert back into trig functions while still keeping the signs right. Ultimately, all the $s$'s will cancel out (because $s^2 = 1$), so we don't have to worry about it in writing the final answer.

Incidentally, in my opinion it's easier not to actually solve for $x$: we can manage the substitution just from the knowledge that

$$ \tan x = s \sqrt{u-1} $$

from which we can derive

$$ \sec^2 x \, dx = s \frac{1}{2} (u-1)^{-1/2} du $$

and, of course, the original equation you set up lets us substitute $\sec^2 x = u$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I must admit, I got a little bit lost when you introduced the local constant, I don't think I studied enough to be able to apply that into my integration yet. But now, I know why I was seeing the error. By the way, can I just confirm, the reason the original solution worked when getting rid of the powers (without introducing modulus) is because tan(x) is valid for the entire range right?

Comment: You can think of $s$ just as a placeholder for $1$ and $-1$, so that you can solve both the $+$ and the $-$ case simultaneously; otherwise, you would have to solve the problem once for the intervals where $x$ such that $x = \pi n + \arctan \sqrt{u-1}$ and then a second time for the intervals where $x$ such that $x = \pi n - \arctan \sqrt{u-1}$. (and technically, you should verify that both sides give the same answer where they overlap at $x = \pi n$ exactly)

Comment: There are a couple ways to think about why getting rid of the powers works -- the way I like is to talk about *analytic functions* (roughly speaking, functions that equal their power series). Your integrand is analytic, and so the antiderivative is analytic too. A neat fact about analytic functions of real numbers is that if an identity $f(x) = g(x)$ holds in any interval -- e.g. in $(\pi n, \pi n + \pi/2)$, then it automatically holds in *any* interval in its domain that overlaps that one -- e.g. the whole interval $(\pi n-\pi/2, \pi n + \pi/2)$.

Comment: ... so if you solve the problem just for those $x$ where $\tan(x) > 0$ (in which case your work accounts for the sign correctly), then in this problem, the solution automatically works everywhere.

Comment: That is enormously helpful, thanks again :)

Answer (score 3):

Your result is *almost* valid.

Taking a different approach, using Integration by Parts from the start:

Note that $\sec^2x = \frac{d}{dx} (\tan x)$.

We can use integration by parts:

$u = \sec^2 x \implies\,du = 2\sec^2 x \tan x\,dx$

$dv = \sec^2 x \,dx\implies \, v = \tan x$.

$$\int \sec^4 x \,dx = \sec^2x\tan x - 2\int \tan^2 x \sec^2 x$$

Now, the remaining integral can be easily solved by substitution: $w = \tan x,\;\implies dw = \sec^2 x$: $$2\int \tan^2 x \sec^2 x \,dx = 2\int w^2 \,dw = \dfrac 23 w + c$$

---

Putting the above together gives us:

$$\int \sec^4 x \,dx = \sec^2x\tan x - \frac 23 \tan^3 x + C$$

---

Note: Your answer is very, very close, and can be manipulated algebraically to closely match the above:

$$\frac{1}{2}\Big(2(\underbrace{\tan^2{x}+1}_{\sec^2 x})\underbrace{(\tan^2{x})^{\frac{1}{2}}}_{|\tan x|}-\frac{4}{3}\underbrace{(\tan^2{x})^{3/2}}_{|\tan^3 x|}\Big)
= \sec^2 |\tan x| - \frac 23 |\tan^3 x| + C$$

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Also, applying the integration by parts formula would give $\sec^2 x\tan x-2\int\sec^2 x\tan^2 x\,dx$ I believe, not what you have.

Comment: Yes, @David. Corrected. I have addressed the OP's question.

Comment: Thank you very much. My solution had the issue that I doesn't work unless I actually get rid of the powers (as you pointed out), but I  really didn't understand why. Which was why I figured something was wrong and I came on here. You have all been super helpful

Comment: You're very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is not direct enough.

$\sec^2x \,dx = d(tan x)$

$\int \sec^4 x \,dx$

$= \int sec^2x\sec^2x \,dx$

$= \int sec^2x \,d(tan x)$

$= \int (1 + tan^2x)\,d(tan x)$

$= \int d(tan x) + \int tan^2x \,d(tan x)$

$= ...$